# Adding "-type f" is causing errors from "find" when a directory contains files with special characters on OS X

Tags: bash, macos, shell, find

I'm try to create MD5 checksums of hundreds of thousands of photos on external drives using the following command on OS X 10.9.5.  I'm getting a bunch of errors though.  I'm using find with nul terminated file names piped to xargs because I think it runs fastest.

`find . -type f -not -name "checksums.md5" -print0 | xargs -0 md5 -r > checksums.md5`

I've narrowed it down to the use of `-type f`, which you can see in this following example:

```
mymac:Finals user$ find . -name "0153*"
./0153_IMG_4812_Coniston village.jpg

mymac:Finals user$ find . -name "0153*" -type f
./0153_IMG_4812_Coniston village.jpg
find: ./0154_IMG_4814_Après hike.jpg: No such file or directory

mymac:Finals user$ find . -name "0154*"
./0154_IMG_4814_Après hike.jpg

mymac:Finals user$ find . -name "0154*" -type f
find: ./0154_IMG_4814_Après hike.jpg: No such file or directory
```

When I run the original command over my hard drive, I see a bunch of these "No such file or directory" errors, and those files are skipped don't get checksummed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it really complain about a file starting with "0154" when you use the name pattern "0153*"? I would think it wouldn't even bother checking the type, since the name didn't match the pattern. Some other thoughts: what file system do the external drives use? Pipe the output and stderr of those `find` commands through `hexdump -C` and compare the bytes of the file name in both cases. Also compare with a hex dump of the output of `ls` on that same directory.

Comment: Yes it does complain!!!!  Let me try your suggestion

Comment: Try `export LC_TYPE=C` before running `find` maybe.

Comment: Difficult to show a formatted reply, but you're on to something with the filesystem.  The files are on NTFS drives, but the error doesn't happen if the files are copied locally (HFS).  Hexdump is showing the same values of "65 cc 80" whether the file is on an HFS or NTFS drive.  Actually I had some difficulty because "ls 0154*" on the NTFS drive also fails, so I had to use "find" without "-type f"

Comment: `export LC_TYPE=C` doesn't help.

Comment: Try just using `ls` on the directory, no glob pattern. Obviously, you'll have to search the hex dump. Or you could filter it with `grep` before piping it into `hexdump -C`. I.e. `ls | grep 0154 | hexdump -C`.

Comment: @Clam Maybe you overwrote `find` somehow. Try `command find ...`

Comment: @KenThomases: you were right about the file system.  I looked at the folder on a Windows machine.  The file shows up ok in Explorer, and opens in Windows Photo Viewer.  md5summer though couldn't handle it.  I copied the filename from Explorer in to notepad and discovered that a Unicode character was used for the E-grave.  I replaced this with the regular ASCII version (byte: 0xE8) and this resolved the problem for the file under OS X.  Funny thing is, `hexdump -C` shows the same UTF-8 character sequence for the broken and fixed filenames: `65 cc 80`.

Comment: Did you consider asking on the Apple Stack Exchange site, [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but I have a work-around: do not copy the files from an HFS drive to NTFS using Apple's HFS drivers (in Bootcamp), but do it either via SMB or VMWare Fusion's shared folders (effectively SMB?)

There are two ways to create an e-grave character.  One is to use extended ASCII 0xE8 from CP1252, the other as I've just learnt is apparently to use Unicode bytes 0x0065 (regular letter 'e', ASCII 0x65) + 0x0300 (combining grave accent).

When I copied the file in Bootcamp, the file name contains UTF-16le byte sequence 0x65 0x00 0x00 0x03 (regular letter 'e' + combining grave accent)

When I copied the file in VMWare fusion by either VMWare's shared folder or via a file share, the filename contains UTF-16le byte sequence 0xE800 (Windows Code Page 1252 extended ASCII e-grave character).

Back under OS X, piping the output of `find` to `hexdump -C` gives the same UTF-8 byte sequence for both variants of this character: `65 cc 80`.  This is presumably why things are falling apart for me under OS X.